# Ayuda de mandar respuestas en jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tengo una pantalla de encuestas y quería saber cómo cargaría el texto de los radios seleccionados en otra pantalla?

[image: Imagen mostrando un dialogo modal]

Comment: saludos y bienvenid@ a SOes, agrega más detalles por favor, caso contrario tu pregunta tiende potencialmente a ser cerrada por ser demasiado amplia y/o no estar claro lo que se pregunta, si deseas buenas respuestas, mayores detalles agrega y mucho mejor si colocas el código :D Saludos

Comment: Esta bien y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal sería que guardaras esta información en alguna base de datos, y se llamara la información desde la otra página.

El problema es que si utilizas solo `Javascript` del lado del cliente, al recargar la página se eliminan las variables que creas.

Es necesario que lo guardes y llames esos datos.

Te recomendaría leer algo sobre `FIREBASE`es muy fácil y si no tienes conocimientos avanzados seguro te servirá.

Comment: Es que el problema es que me impusieron unas tablas y no quieren que use otra base de datos y los valores se guardan numericos y quiere que los enlace a la respuesta

Comment: Busca acerca de Local Storage, tal vez te puede ser util. Un abrazo.

Answer (score 0):

No se si esto te valdra

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST", //POST O GET 
      url: url, 
      data: data,
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
    });
```

Para recoger el valor de un radiobutton

```
<input type="radio" name="edad" id="edad1" value="20"> 20<br>
<input type="radio" name="edad" id="edad2" value="30"> 30<br>
<input type="radio" name="edad" id="edad3" value="40"> 40 

var a = $('input:radio[name=edad]:checked').val();
```

En la función ajax de jquery en data (datos que vas a mandar) enviar la variable 'a'

Aquí tienes mas información: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Si tiene que cargar en otra página, la única manera que conozco es que usaras cookies y almacenaras ahí los valores seleccionados para posteriormente recuperarlas en la otra página.

Como te han comentado, necesitarías de base de datos, o en su defecto, usar PHP, y una vez enviado el formulario, cargar la siguiente página con los datos enviados.

Answer (score 0):

Si no dispones donde almacenar los datos de la encuesta en el servidor, puedes usar la memoria del navegador en javascript *localStorage*  o *sessionStorage*.